# Cannot fetch the Doctrine EntityManager with autowire in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, service, autowired, entitymanager

Well, I'm going crazy, there's something I don't get with the Symfony (3.3) autowiring stuff.
I've read those resources :
http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html
http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html 
and others that I can't post because I need 10 reputation.
I've also read many articles/stackoverflow posts, but with no luck.

I've tried to set up my services, and it almost works, it's just that the EntityManager is null, so I can't call `->getRepository()` on it. The error happens on the line like this in my factory:

```
$databaseTournament = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Tournament')
    ->find($tournament);
```

> "Call to a member function getRepository() on null"

It seems to find the services correctly but never injects the EntityManager in the factory. I've tried to configure things explicitely in the **services.yml**, but I never managed to make it work.

I'm trying to figure it ou since yesterday, but I'm getting really confused. Could you help me ? Thank you in advance ! :)

Here are my files :

### services.yml:

```
parameters:
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false
    AppBundle\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
        exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository,Tests}'
    AppBundle\Controller\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Controller'
        public: true
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

### EntryFactory:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Factory;

use AppBundle\Entity\Entry;
use AppBundle\Entity\Team;
use AppBundle\Entity\Tournament;
use AppBundle\Exception\InvalidEntryArgumentException;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityNotFoundException;

class EntryFactory
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function createEntry($tournament, $team, $eliminated = false)
    {
        $entry = new Entry();

        if ($tournament instanceof Tournament) {
            $entry->setTournament($tournament);
        }
        elseif (is_int($tournament) && $tournament >= 0) {
            $databaseTournament = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Tournament')->find($tournament);
            if (is_null($databaseTournament)) {
                throw new EntityNotFoundException('Tournament (id:'.$tournament.') not found.');
            }
            else {
                $entry->setTournament($databaseTournament);
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new InvalidEntryArgumentException('Could not determine the Tournament argument.');
        }

        if ($team instanceof Team) {
            $entry->setTeam($team);
        }
        elseif (is_int($team) && $team >= 0) {
            $databaseTeam = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Team')->find($team);
            if (is_null($databaseTeam)) {
                throw new EntityNotFoundException('Team (id:'.$team.') not found.');
            }
            else {
                $entry->setTeam($databaseTeam);
            }
        }
        else {
             throw new InvalidEntryArgumentException('Could not determine the Team argument.');
        }


        $entry->setEliminated($eliminated);
        return $entry;
    }
}
```

### EntryController:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\Entry;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityNotFoundException;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;
use Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\Annotation\ApiDoc;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolationList;
use AppBundle\Factory;

class EntryController extends FOSRestController
{
    /**
     * @ApiDoc(
     *     resource=true,
     *     section="Entries",
     *     description="Creates a new entry.",
     *     statusCodes={
     *          201="Returned when created.",
     *          400="Returned when a violation is raised by validation.",
     *          404="Returned when a team or a tournament is not found."
     *     }
     * )
     *
     * @Rest\Post(
     *     path="/entries",
     *     name="app_entry_create"
     * )
     * @Rest\View(statusCode=201)
     * @Rest\RequestParam(
     *     name="tournamentId",
     *     requirements="\d+",
     *     nullable=false,
     *     description="The id of the tournament in which the team enters."
     * )
     * @Rest\RequestParam(
     *     name="teamId",
     *     requirements="\d+",
     *     nullable=false,
     *     description="The id of the team entering the tournament."
     * )
     *
     * @param $tournamentId
     * @param $teamId
     * @param ConstraintViolationList $violationList
     * @param Factory\EntryFactory $entryFactory
     * @return Entry|View
     * @throws EntityNotFoundException
     * @internal param $id
     * @internal param Entry $entry
     */
    public function createEntryAction($tournamentId, $teamId, ConstraintViolationList $violationList,
                                      Factory\EntryFactory $entryFactory)
    {
        if (count($violationList)) {
            return $this->view($violationList, Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        $entry = $entryFactory->createEntry($tournamentId,$teamId);
        $em->persist($entry);
        $em->flush();
        return $entry;
    }
}
```

**edit:**

I must add that I've tried this and it doesn't work either:

in the **services.yml:**

```
AppBundle\Factory\EntryFactory:
    public: true
    arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
```

in the **EntryFactory:**

```
public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
{
    $this->em = $em;
}
```

**edit 2:**

I've also tried to disable everything new : still the same error

```
AppBundle\Factory\EntryFactory:
        autowire: false
        autoconfigure: false
        public: true
        arguments:
            $em: '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'
```

Same with disabling the folder in the default config :

```
AppBundle\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
        exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository,Tests,Factory}'
```

Comment: And you are using S3.3?  Not 3.2 or earlier?

Comment: Hello Jason, I've just checked, I'm on v3.3.5

Comment: please post your `AppKernel::bundles` and composer.json configuration.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to force [autowiring Dependency Injection in Symfony 3.3](https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/service_container/autowiring.html#an-autowiring-example) or later, without having to explicitly define the entity manager for each service. You can add [an alias of the desired entity manager service](https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/service_container/alias_private.html#aliasing).

```
#app/config/services.yml
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false

    AppBundle\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
        exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository,Tests}'

    AppBundle\Controller\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Controller/*'
        public: true
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface: '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'

   #custom services below here
   #...
```

This will then allow Symfony to determine `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface` as the service you want to inject.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class EntryFactory
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }
    
    //...
}
```

End result will be in your services configuration as:

```
return $this->services['AppBundle\Factory\EntryFactory'] = new \AppBundle\Factory\EntryFactory(${($_ = isset($this->services['doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager']) ? $this->services['doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager'] : $this->load('getDoctrine_Orm_DefaultEntityManagerService.php')) && false ?: '_'});
```

> Note: Be sure to warmup your Symfony cache to ensure new service
> declarations are created.
>
> ```
> php composer.phar install
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> php composer.phar install --no-scripts
> php bin/console --env=dev cache:clear --no-warmup
> php bin/console --env=dev cache:warmup
> ```